# Simplest way to delete an existing Route53 Record with Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have existing Route53 records in a Hosted Zone that I want to delete. I didn't use boto3 to create these records. How can I describe an existing record and use the description to update/delete the record?

For example:

```py
definition = client.describe_record_record_set(record_set_id)
client.change_resource_record_sets(definition)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Python SDK | Route 53 - delete resource record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196558/aws-python-sdk-route-53-delete-resource-record)

Comment: That should do it.